# Function that echo string then replace letters

Tags: php, string, function

Im new to php. Here's what i am trying to do: echo "Trololololo" then `str_replace` "o" by "a" then echo the modified chain of character then `str_replace` again all "a" by "i" and then echo the modified chain again. My attempt so far:

```
function sing_a_song(){
   $var="Trololololololol<br>";
   echo $var;
   str_replace("o","a",$var);
   echo $var;
   str_replace("a","i",$var);
   echo $var;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I dont know php, but try see if str_replace updates $var, or if it needs to be assigned eg $foo = str_replace(...)

Answer (score 2):

**Assign** result of `str_replace` to a variable:

```
$var = str_replace("o","a",$var);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in  single line as well like this. In the following example o replaced by a and a replaced by i.

```
function sing_a_song(){
  $var="Trololololololol<br>";
  $str = ['o','a'];
  $rplc =['a','i'];
  $output = str_replace($str,$rplc,$var);
  echo $output;
}

sing_a_song();
result will be like- Trililililililil
```

Comment: please accept this as answer and an upvote if it help you